# Recommendations overlap in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I do not know how, but when writing code, two panels open for suggestions and both are opened in a row. Unfortunately I couldn't find how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These things sometimes be caused by plugins like CodeRush and Resharper that working together. I think it is necessary to use only one of these plugins. But I am not sure. The problem seems to be caused by the window being unable to be adjusted.
You can follow these steps from Visual Studio.

1. Window -> Close All Documents
2. Window -> Reset Window Layout

Exit Visual Studio to be sure, then go back in.

**When the same happens to me, update:** 
In fact, the overlapping things are that both Resharper and IntelliSense show completion list after a character is typed. To prevent this, it is necessary to turn off either the Resharper or IntelliSense related feature. I prefered to close IntelliSense's completion list with help from [this site](https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-turn-off-autocomplete). For this, I followed these steps:

- From Visual Studio, select “Tools” > “Options“.
- Select “Text Editor” in the left pane.
- Select the language you are using (C#, C++, Basic, etc.).
- For C# and Basic, choose “IntelliSense“. For C or C++, choose “Advanced“, then scroll to the “IntelliSense” section.
- For C# and Basic, check the “Show completion list after a character is typed” to disable it. For C/C++, you will have a few options, such as “Disable Auto Updating“, “Disable Squiggles“, and “Disable #include “Auto Complete“. Set any of these to “True” to turn them off.